# Cannot install ia32-libs-gtk on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, software-installation

```
Donatas ubuntu14 @: ~ $ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk: i386
Reading package lists ... Done
Construct the dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
N: Ignoring file ia32-libs-raring.list "catalog" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ "because it is the wrong file name extension
N: Ignoring file ia32-libs-raring.list "catalog" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ "because it is the wrong file name extension
E: Could not find package ia32-libs-gtk
```

Comment: `N: Ignoring file ia32-libs-raring.list "catalog" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ "because it is the wrong file name extension` You seem to be following an outdated guide. Could you provide a link?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Ne Why do you want to install ia32-libs-gtk?

Answer (score 2):

The package ia32-libs-gtk is not available in Ubuntu 14.04. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
```

This package depends on i386 versions of packages that were removed from ia32-libs and transitioned to multi-arch. This allows applications using ia32-libs in previous Ubuntu releases to continue functioning without missing libraries.

Also there should not be a blank space in `: i386` instead it should be `:i386`. For additional information see this question: [How to install ia32-libs in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182765/how-to-install-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr).